# Resizing the div horizontal and vertical in angular 5 through Mouse pointer

Tags: css, angular

i am new to angular 5 . i have to implement Resizing the div horizontal and vertical  through Mouse pointer.Please help me to implement this one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to use Angular for this task, however you can use the [ngClass] bindings to add and remove classes.

Angular method:

HTML:

```
 <div (mouseenter)="modifyCssClass()" [ngClass]="myClasses"></div>
```

Typescript:

```
myClasses = "['default-class']"
modifyCssClass() {
    this.myClasses = "['new-class-with-horizontal-and-vertical-dims']"

}
```

Pure CSS method:

```
   div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
   }
   div:hover {
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
   }
```

Comment: while dragging the div horizontal and vertical postion has to resize in angular 5.Please help me to implement this functionality.  for example please refer this link. http://jsfiddle.net/BMwTy/